# How can I replace pd intervals with integers in python

Tags: python, pandas, intervals

How can I replace pd intervals with integers

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['age'] = [43, 76, 27, 8, 57, 32, 12, 22]
age_band = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
df['age_bands']= pd.cut(df['age'], bins=age_band, ordered=True)
```

output:

```
    age age_bands
0   43  (40, 50]
1   76  (70, 80]
2   27  (20, 30]
3   8   (0, 10]
4   57  (50, 60]
5   32  (30, 40]
6   12  (10, 20]
7   22  (20, 30]
```

now I want to add another column to replace the bands with a single number (int). but I could not

for example this did not work :

```
df['age_code']= df['age_bands'].replace({'(40, 50]':4})
```

how can I get a column looks like this?

```
    age_bands   age_code
0   (40, 50]      4
1   (70, 80]      7
2   (20, 30]      2
3   (0, 10]       0
4   (50, 60]      5
5   (30, 40]      3
6   (10, 20]      1
7   (20, 30]      2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to the first digit from every interval, then, you can use `pd.apply` to achieve what you want as follows:

```
df["age_code"] = df["age_bands"].apply(lambda band: str(band)[1])
```

However, note this may not be very efficient for a large dataframe,

To convert the column values to int datatype, you can use `pd.to_numeric`,

```
df["age_code"] = pd.to_numeric(df['age_code'])
```

Answer (score 0):

As the column contains `pd.Interval` objects, use its property `left`

```
df['age_code'] = df['age_bands'].apply(lambda interval: interval.left // 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by simply adding a second [**`pd.cut`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and define `labels` argument.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['age'] = [43, 76, 27, 8, 57, 32, 12, 22]
age_band = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
df['age_bands']= pd.cut(df['age'], bins=age_band, ordered=True)

#This is the part of code you need to add
age_labels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
df['age_code']= pd.cut(df['age'], bins=age_band, labels=age_labels, ordered=True)
```

##### `>>> print(df)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary of bins and map it to the `age_bands` column:

```
bins_sorted = sorted(pd.cut(df['age'], bins=age_band, ordered=True).unique())
bins_dict = {key: idx for idx, key in enumerate(bins_sorted)}
df['age_code'] = df.age_bands.map(bins_dict).astype(int)
```